# Block Website in android using wifi SSID

Tags: android, web, wifi, block

how can i block website in android which is controlled through wifi SSID black list, i mean when i block facebook for specified SSID then it should be block facebook only for that SSID.

my requirement is to block website using SSID filter for diffrent wifi. like if person at the office there should be block entertaining sites but when it comes to another ssid which is already maintain some black list for websites it should block those websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<WifiConfiguration> configuredNetworks = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks(); 
if(configuredNetworks != null)
{ 
    for(WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration : configuredNetworks)
    { 
       if(wifiConfiguration.status == WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED || 
          wifiConfiguration.status == WifiConfiguration.Status.CURRENT)
          { 
              ScanResult scan = map.get(wifiConfiguration.SSID);
              if(scan != null)
              { 
                 // Here you have the current connected WiFi
                 String wifiName = scan.SSID;
              }
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks you, if you know anything about how to block particular website plz post.

Comment: i got error at map.get(wifiConfiguration.SSID) here what is map